# Minor leak from PRV Adjustment Bolt

Tags: plumbing, leak

I had a PRV installed a few months ago to reduce my home's water pressure to 80 PSI. I recently noticed some additional sounds from my toilets, and upon investigating found that my PSI had jumped to 100 PSI.

So, I loosened the adjustment lock nut on the PRV and then rotated the adjustment bolt CC to decrease the pressure.  To my surprise, after moving the adjustment bolt I started to see a leak coming from the base of the adjustment bolt!

After some tweaking I think I've been able to reduce the PSI to 80 and stop the leak, but just barely.

Is my PRV defective, or is this expected/user error on my part?  Is there a possible mitigation besides replacing the entire PRV?

The combination of the creeping pressure and leak at the adjustment bolt both seem suspicious, especially on a fairly new PRV.

Thanks

[image: Leaking PRV]

Answer (score 1):

Thats seems likely to be related and defective/failed.

Specifically, the typical design of a pressure regulator (which is the general class to which pressure reducing valves belong) has a rubber (or sometimes thin stainless steel) diaphragm between the working fluid and the area where that adjustment screw comes out. Yours may actually be teflon, according to the parts diagrams for some of the valves linked below.

There should be no water between the diaphragm and the screw threads, so there should be no leak at the adjustment screw.

If it's "relatively new" and has a warranty/guarantee in force, use it. If not, there should be a rebuild kit to replace the diaphragm, and perhaps a few other parts, to restore it to like-new condition. I cannot make out your model number (...possibly 600XL), but your manufacturer is "Zurn" and I was able to find [a page for their parts/rebuild kits.](https://www.zurn.com/products/repair-parts/water-safety-and-control/pressure-reducing-valve)

There appear to be supplementary or different diaphragms for "high inlet pressure" and depending on what you have, that might be a thing you could add or upgrade to when rebuilding it, if it does not have that now, as it could be a reason for early failure, depending what your inlet pressure is, and what the valve model you have was designed for as "normal" and "high" inlet pressures. Contact the manufacturer for advice....